# AWS S3 Presigned Post url multipart uploads

Tags: amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

Is this possible?  I have looked (and looked again).  Multipart uploads are clearly possible using regular presigned URLs (ie. PUT), but I can't find any documentation to suggest that you can use them with POST.  I found some examples, but they seem incorrect if only because they do not show the uploadID anywhere and, from what I understand, the multipart upload on S3 (logically) requires an uploadID to be able to reassemble the parts after you end the process.

Comment: S3 supports POST for single file uploads so you can upload with HTML only.  For pretty much any scenario involving multi-part uploads, you'll need to bring in javascript, so you can upload the parts with individual PUT calls.

Comment: @AnonCoward Thanks very much for your reply. I do use Javascript to setup POST as well using presigned urls, and I understand why you need JS for multipart.  I was just hoping that you could do multiple parts with the POST urls as well, but it doesn't sound promising. Thanks again.